# spark join function error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a big dataframe and I want to join it with a small csv file. 
So I broadcast my small file:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/zed/file/app_desc")
val id_dec = sc.broadcast(rdd.map(line=>(line.split(";")(0),line.split(";")(1))).collectAsMap)
```

and I make a function to get the id (input) and return the description

```
def extract_connection_type(input:Integer): String = {
  if (input == null || input.length() == 0)
    input;
  else try {
    id_dec.value.get(input)
  } catch {
     case e: Exception => throw new IOException("UDF:Caught exception processing input row :" + input + e.toString);
  }
}
```

Afterwards, when I create my schema I use this function to make my join

```
def structure(line: String): structure_Ot = {
  val fields = line.split("\\\t",-1);
  val Name1 = fields(0);
  val Name2 = fields(1);
  val Appd = fields(2).toInt;
  val App = extract_connection_type(Appd);
  val ot_str = new structure_Ot(Name1, Name2, App)
  ot_str
}
```

but I get this error:

```
<console>:93: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Int
```

and even when I change my input to Integer; my error change to:

```
found   : String
required: Int
```

What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of type mismatches in your code, you'll need to fix them all:

1. `id_dec` has the type `Broadcast[Map[String, String]]` (because you create an `RDD[(String, String)]` and then call `collectAsMap` and `broadcast` on the result); In your `extract_connection_type`, you call `id_dec.value.get(input)` where `input` has type `Int`, and the map's key is a `String`. You can fix that either by changing the type of `input` to `String`, or by changing `id_dec` into a `Broadcast[Map[Int, String]]` by collecting and broadcasting an `RDD[(Int, String)]` in the first place; If you choose the former, you'll have to adjust your `structure` function too, so it passes a `String` and not an `Int`.
2. Another issue in using `id_dec.value.get(input)` is that `get` returns an `Option[V]` (where `V` is the type of the map's values) and not a `V`. You can use the `apply` method (implicitly) instead: `id_dec.value(input)`, which will return a `String` or throw an exception if no matching key found

Altogether, this is a compiling version of your code:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/zed/file/app_desc")
val id_dec: Broadcast[Map[String, String]] = sc.broadcast(rdd.map(line=>(line.split(";")(0),line.split(";")(1))).collectAsMap)

def extract_connection_type(input: String): String = {
  if (input == null || input.length() == 0)
    input
  else try {
    id_dec.value(input)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => throw new IOException("UDF:Caught exception processing input row :" + input + e.toString);
  }
}

def structure(line: String): structure_Ot = {
  val fields = line.split("\\\t",-1)
  val Name1 = fields(0)
  val Name2 = fields(1)
  val Appd = fields(2)
  val App = extract_connection_type(Appd)
  val ot_str = structure_Ot(Name1, Name2, App.toInt)
  ot_str
}
```

A good way to resolve these issues yourself is to explicitly type each value you define; That way you'll see where the error is more clearly - if you expect `id_dec` to have a certain type, the error will point to its assignment if there's an issue where the wrong type is assigned.

Comment: after applying this solution; i got an empty App; i want to take the App_Description which is a string value.i do this function for join .. i hope you understand me

Comment: i fixed my problem; i have been declaring `App` as an `int` in `structure_Ot`